# How can I screen a URL for files / responses of a certain type?

Tags: java, file, url, download, web-scraping

I have a web page with links pointing to downloadable files. For example:

http://www.mysite.com/download.php?FILE=downloads/programming/various/ebook.pdf

But it can also have navigation links as follows:

http://www.mysite.com/index.php

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?category=programming

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?section=programming&category=various

How can I determine if a URL is pointing to a file as in the first link ? Or inversely, filter out URLs which don't fit ?

Comment: @NewAlexandria Accepted your edit.

Comment: All's good. I have some code that can do the downloads and will incorporate the suggestion to filter files :)

Comment: Great.  Good if you'd give at least one of us the credit for a correct solution.

Comment: Credit given. Thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with your edited question: if you want to filter out files,

> screen the `Content-Type` header.

[Here is an informal list of common mime-types](https://github.com/akitaonrails/cookbooks/blob/master/nginx/files/default/mime.types)

You can inspect response headers to determine if the response will conform, e.g. to an `application/pdf`   But you cannot, just from the URL / URI itself, make this determination.

In fact, I could construct a web application that would respond to the URL `http://myapp.com/test.pdf` with header `Content-Type: image/jpeg` and data of a JPG.

Also, I could really break things by sending a header `Content-Type: image/jpeg` and data of for a *PDF*.

---

Presuming that it wasn't intentionally-broken (as I mentioned above) then you can rely on the response.

**Be aware** if the content itself deviates from the `Content-Type` header then you could have an exploit happen.  This is how the iPhone was jailbroken: through acting on malformed PDF data.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Question has been updated. Yes, the question should be about downloading files AND filtering out web pages. Is `Content-Type` the best possibility ? From what you say it appears it can be manipulated.

Comment: Also, I could check for file size if the host supports it and run a magic bytes check after a download. What do you think ?

Comment: Exploits don't really have much to do with the wrong content-type, rather they have to do with a vulnerability of the handler of that content-type.

Comment: If you're concerned about exploits, then I think you need to evaluate the format of the response.  @Bruno is correct that it's only a danger in what you do with that data - though.

Comment: Also, you can't trust a `.php` URL to return `text/html` content.  It could return `image/jpeg` if the script handles image output such as for an on-page JS graph.  Similarly, a URL or link `http://mysite.com/dough/` may return a `text/html` content type.  even withour redirecting or resolving to another URL like `http://mysite.com/dough/index.asp`

Comment: @NewAlexandria That's true. I've made one such PHP script that resizes images. I'm not that concerned about exploits. Files will simply be downloaded to a user's computer and stored away. The only possible issue is if a user views a file.

Comment: @NewAlexandria, actually it's the other way around, if you're worried about attacks, you should *avoid* content sniffing and dispatch the response to the handler solely based on the content-type, see example [here](http://thomasjaehnel.com/blog/2009/11/attacks-based-on-content-sniffing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Look for a file name-like parameter?

*Any* URL could *respond* with a file when requested.

You have no way of knowing what a URL will respond with until you request it.

Comment: Doesn't it always respond with a file? A HTML-page is also a file

Comment: I sensed that answers would go in this direction. Let me reformulate that. How could I download the PDF, TXT, DOC... and filter  out PHP, HTML and ASP ?

Comment: @Hashmush No, it could respond with a dynamically-constructed stream of bytes, data from a database, anything.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, but that could also be interpreted as a file. The browser/client doesn't know that it's dynamically generated.

Comment: @Hashmush Correct, it doesn't--it doesn't respond with a file, it responds with a stream of bytes. Those bytes might be *from* a file, or they might be made to *look* like a file. But no, there's nothing file-specific about it, and it doesn't always "respond with a file", which is what you said :)

Answer (score 1):

In HTTP, URLs don't point to files, ever; they identify resources, for which you get a representation when your "dereference" that URL (i.e. make a GET request).

Whether the user-agent chooses to store that representation as a file is its own choice. What to do with a representation is guided by the content-type.

You may obtain the content-type using a `HEAD` request. PDF documents should be using `application/pdf` but there are a number of other types. Most browsers tend to save `application/octet-stream` as files, by default. (There are also subtleties about content-type negotiation.)

In Java, you could make a HEAD request using something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
// Check connection.getContentType();
```